# Error in batch norm parameter initialization Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow Slim model described underneath. When I try to run the session, I get errors complying about attempts to use uninitialized values from BatchNorm:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value error/logits/BatchNorm/moving_variance
     [[Node: error/logits/BatchNorm/moving_variance/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@error/logits/BatchNorm/moving_variance"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](error/logits/BatchNorm/moving_variance)]]
```

I can't understand it, since I do use `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`. Why does it happen and how can I prevent it?

```
class Model:

    def __init__(self, representations, labels, is_training, keep_prob):
        self.representations = representations
        self.labels = labels
        self.n_classes = 2
        self.keep_prob_ = keep_prob
        self.is_training_ = is_training

        # Conv 1
        self.conv1_kernel_patch = [5, 5]
        self.conv1_output_chans = 64
        # Pool 1
        self.pool1_patch = [3, 3]
        # Conv 2
        self.conv2_kernel_patch = [5, 5]
        self.conv2_output_chans = 128
        # Pool 2
        self.pool2_patch = [3, 3]
        # Fully connected 1
        self.fc1_neurons = 384
        # Fully connected 2
        self.fc2_neurons = 192


    #@define_scope()
    def prediction(self):
        with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected],
                            activation_fn=tf.nn.crelu,
                            normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
                            normalizer_params={'is_training': self.is_training_, 'decay': 0.95},
                            ):
            x = self.representations

            # Debug
            print("The shape of the input representation is {}".format(np.shape(x)))

            x = slim.conv2d(x, self.conv1_output_chans, self.conv1_kernel_patch, scope='conv1') # args: input, number output channels,kernel patch size
            x = slim.max_pool2d(x, self.pool1_patch, scope='pool1')

            x = slim.conv2d(x, self.conv2_output_chans, self.conv2_kernel_patch, scope='conv2')
            x = slim.max_pool2d(x, self.pool2_patch, scope='pool1')

            x = slim.flatten(x)

            x = slim.fully_connected(x, self.fc1_neurons, scope='fc1')
            x = slim.dropout(x, keep_prob=self.keep_prob_)
            x = slim.fully_connected(x, self.fc2_neurons, scope='fc2')
            x = slim.dropout(x, keep_prob=self.keep_prob_)
            x = slim.fully_connected(x, self.n_classes, activation_fn=None, scope='logits')
        return x

    @define_scope
    def optimize(self):
        logprob = tf.log(self.prediction() + 1e-12)
        cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(self.labels * logprob)
        optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.03)
        return optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

    @define_scope
    def error(self):
        mistakes = tf.not_equal(
            tf.argmax(self.labels, 1), tf.argmax(self.prediction(), 1))
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(mistakes, tf.float32))
```

I train the model with this code:

```
model = Model(representations=representations, labels=labels, keep_prob=keep_prob, is_training=is_training)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

train_iterations = 10000
validation_checks = 1000

for _ in range(validation_checks):

    representations_val, labels_val = input.get_validation_batch()

    error = sess.run(model.error, {representations: representations_val, labels: labels_val, keep_prob: 1.0, is_training: False})
    print('Validation error {:6.2f}%'.format(100 * error))
    for _ in range(int(train_iterations/validation_checks)):

        representations_trainbat, labels_trainbat = input.get_train_batch(2)
        sess.run(model.optimize, {representations: representations_trainbat, labels: labels_trainbat, keep_prob: 0.9, is_training: False})
```

Comment: Your train has `is_training: False`, needs to be `True`?

Comment: yes, indeed, thanks for pointing out. I had corrected that in between. It does not change the outcome though.